# How does servlet container instantiate session for several "first" requests?

Tags: java, session, servlets

It is obvious that browsers send several request before render html page. Say that user opens an page and browser send 3 request which is catched by [servlet Filter](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html):

```
public class MyFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        saveVisitorQueue = new SaveVisitorQueue();
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (req.getSession().getAttrbute("name")!=null) {
            req.getSession().setAttrbute("name", "helloValue" + new Date());            
        }
    }
}
```

The first request "initializes" session atrribute, but what about others? If user accesses page first time requests do not have any cookies with session id. And this id will be set only after first request is processed.

So does other sent request has same session and same attribute? And how server "establish" session for several "first" requests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally there won't be several "first" requests. The browser needs to get the page it's displaying first, and then as it's parsing that page, will request resources referenced by that page (images, style sheets, JavaScript, etc.), usually when it encounters them (although there are various ways to modify that) and in parallel (up to some browser-specific limit) and often on the same TCP/IP connection (depending on the browser and server). So the first page request should set the session ID, and subsequent requests will have the session cookie.

Answer (score 0):

How does it work in browser?
The fisrt request ask for some html.
The server send back some Html and... a sessionId.
The browser parse the html and do some request (css, js, images) to be able to render the page correctly and send back the sessionId to the server.

Answer (score 0):

The browser does send multiple requests to the server while he is rendering the HTML. 
The first time the server returns the HTML to the browser, and then the browser starts rendering. When the browser sees a tag like ,  or , that means that he has to make another request to get the associated resource, but he doesn't send request for the whole web page again, just for the resource.
About the Session object, the first time you call request.getSession(), it will create a new session and a cookie with the session id, only if the client supports cookies. The next time when the user makes a request, request.getSession() will return the current session associated with the request. So, the answer to your question is : yes, the other sent requests will have the same session and the same session attributes until the session is invalidated or timed out.
For more information, I suggest reading the book "Head First Servlets and JSP", I find it very helpful and fun to read. In it, you have extensive explanation of how servlets work.